# Packing all dynamic data into a single Vuex store

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I'm working on a web application which consists of various pages that rely on ajax calls (via AXIOS) for either fetching data from the server or communicating data back to the server. However, the data that is fetched from the server is 99% of times intact during the lifecycle of a session meaning that it will not be changed (i.e. only displayed to user while involving very low update frequency). Moreover, this data, is just pure text including links to contents, formatted as a JSON Object.

I have just found about Vuex, and I have been thinking about packing all these get Ajax requests scattered across different components and centralize them in a Vuex Store in a way that, when the application loads, all required data would be fetched from the server so that no more communication with the server to get such data during the lifecycle of the session would be needed (while only getting the contents such as images, audio, etc via links).

Is Vuex appropriate for this purpose? Is this a good idea at all (based on the concept of speeding up navigations)?

Comment: Vuex is meant to manage complexity, if you're barely going to update your data, I'm not sure there really is a point in adding it to your application

Comment: @Axnyff: it is exactly the opposite, I'm not trying to barely update data, I'm trying to provide data in a centralized way via Vuex.

Comment: After centralized data with Vuex you could try to persist data in local storage to avoid ajax call ,take a look at this https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuex-persist, so you can save the current state of your app to localStorage

Comment: @TahaAzzabi: Interesting, Thanks :)

Comment: explained more here https://alligator.io/vuejs/vuex-persist-state/

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, Vuex is meant to manage complexity and in your case you are planning to fetch 99% of the data at the beginning for your app. So, in client-server aspect, you totally don't need it. Keeping your data structured would be enough.

However, you have also the notion [mutation](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/mutations.html) in Vuex. The idea is that you can update the core data only using mutations. In this way, you are protected from unwanted changes and you have a better insight how/in which order your data is changing. So, if you have complex operations on your data (fetched from server and also your apps logic), Vuex would be a good choice.

There are also another interesting features for different kind of apps. Note that is just another trending way to keep your data structured. There are also another strategies but since Vuex is regularly maintained by Vue core team (and it seems to be also in the future), I would suggest it. Especially, if your app keep growing, you will love it more and more. After reading core concepts of [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/core-concepts.html) (or better its logic behind Vuex: **FLUX**), you will have better insight about it.